# Align items in a row that have a start and end items centered vertically

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Material 3

I have the following code but can't align the 3 dot so they are in the centered but currently its at the top. I would like to have it centered vertically so its better aligned with the `project x`

This is how the design looks with the code:

[image]

```
@Composable
fun AgendaCard(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    isAgendaCompleted: Boolean = true
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(120.dp).background(color = Color.Green, shape = RoundedCornerShape(22.dp))) {
        Column {
            Box(modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()) {
                Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp).align(Alignment.TopStart),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                    val agendaStatusIcon = if (isAgendaCompleted) {
                        painterResource(id = R.drawable.completed)
                    } else {
                        painterResource(id = R.drawable.incomplete)
                    }
                    Icon(painter = agendaStatusIcon, contentDescription = "Agenda status")
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
                    Text(text = "Project X")
                }
                OptionButton(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp, end = 16.dp).align(Alignment.CenterEnd))
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(14.dp))
            Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 48.dp),
                text = "This is the project tasky that needs")
        }
        Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 12.dp, end = 16.dp).align(alignment = Alignment.BottomEnd) ,
            text = "Mar 5, 10:30 - Mar 5, 11:00")
    }
}


@Composable
fun OptionButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.DarkOptionButton) {
    Row(modifier.wrapContentWidth()) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.white_dot),
            contentDescription = "option button 1",
            tint = color
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(3.dp))
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.white_dot),
            contentDescription = "option button 2",
            tint = color
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(3.dp))
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.white_dot),
            contentDescription = "option button 3",
            tint = color
        )
    }
}
```

And this is the figma design

[image]

Comment: Why are you using Box + Row + other Row inside?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I have removed that row. And fixed the issue I was having but not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: You can also use only 1 Row without Box

Comment: Are the 3 dots, 3 different icons? or just 1 icon?

Comment: They are 3 icons. I have posted the composable for them that creates them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your layout. You can remove the `Box` and use a `Row` as parent container, applying the weight modifier to the `Text`

Something like:

```
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_home_24), contentDescription = "Agenda status")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
        Text(
            text = "Project X",
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        )

        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            Icon(
                //...
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(3.dp))
            Icon(
                ///
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(3.dp))
            Icon(
                ///
            )
        }
    }
```

[image]